# why am I getting only 1 object entry from my fetch response instead of the list of entries

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

How can I receive all the entries as a response when I fetch instead of only having 1 value as a response? For example, the next value the fetch returns for me is {"next":"/heretagium"}. Once I put in 'heretagium' in place of "/hustengium that will allow me to get the next one. However, i want to receive all of them

```
   let next_url = "/hustengium" 
    let uri = "http://fasttrack.herokuapp.com/"  
    let h = new Headers()
        h.append('Accept', 'application/json')

    let req = new Request(uri + next_url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: h,
        mode: 'cors'

    })  



   fetch(req )
    .then(response => response.json() )
    .then(data => {
        let str = JSON.stringify(data) 
        document.querySelector("div#output").textContent = str
    
     console.log(data["next"] )
    })

    .catch(err => {
        let nm = err.name
        let msg = err.message
        alert(`CATCH: ${nm} ${msg}`)
    })
```

Comment: You cannot get all of them at once. You need to create some sort of loop, or a recursive function

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get them all at once. Just like [Russian Nesting Dolls](https://www.google.com/search?q=russian+dolls&source=lnms&tbm=isch&biw=1920&bih=979). To get to the smallest one, you have to open them all one by one:

```js
(function loop(root, path) {
  const proxy = 'http://cors-everywhere.herokuapp.com/';
  fetch(proxy + root + path, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      if (res.next) loop(root, res.next);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
})('http://fasttrack.herokuapp.com', '/');
```

Comment: Good luck, you're only 2 steps away from the end. The final one asks you to send them an email at an address you have to figure out. Pretty fun challenge, but a little short

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The main problems were that I didn't make my url and path passed in dynamic which forced it to call the same url over and over again.

```
  fetch(`${url}${next}` )
    .then(response => response.json() )
    .then(data => {
           section.innerHtml = data.next
         if(data.next) {
           loop(data.next)
}
       
    })

loop()
```